# Creating C# events with Visual Studio Modeling Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, uml, code-generation

I started playing with UML modeling in VS. I tried creating diagram with a few classes, connect them and generate some code from the model - after installing the Feature Pack, everything seems to work fine.

However what I am missing is the ability to declare events - which play rather major part in .Net (and are often key to the design).

**How do I declare events in the UML Class Diagram in Visual Studio?**

**EDIT:**

To clear things up. I'm *not* interested in anything related to the Class Diagram feature present in C# projects in Visual Studio for some time.

This question is related to [Modeling Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409445.aspx), which is a new feature in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Comment: In my mind, isn't possible to deal with events in UML. I've tried and never found how to do, so good question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML is implementation language agnostic. The *correct* way to define a language specific idiom in UML is by using a [stereotype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype_%28UML%29).  A stereotype is a specialisation of UML metaclass. Define a [profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465143.aspx) which extends Class into an EventHandler and Event *stereotype* which extends Message.  Then apply those stereotypes to classes in your models appropriately.  You can then place the language specific idiom implementation details in the stereotype.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. After 20 more minutes of studying the documentation I finally found out that there is C# profile with "event" stereotype provided with the Feature Pack. However the code generation templates seem to be completely ignoring attributes with this stereotype. I will keep looking into this, so I will not mark this as the answer yet. However I will grant you the bounty (it would otherwise expire).

Comment: @Matěj Zábský: I noticed the same behavior as you. I filed a bug [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/725112/generate-code-in-vs2010-modeling-project-events-ignored). If you have access to that site, please vote it up for expedited attention.

Comment: @Matěj: Update: MS has responded to the bug report with a promise to address the issue in the next release. They have also provided a workaround (which I haven't had the opportunity to test yet). See the comments thread [on the issue page](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/725112/generate-code-in-vs2010-modeling-project-events-ignored#details) for details.

Comment: @Kmote I can confirm this issue problem is fixed in VS 2012 RC. Thanks for nudging microsoft to fix this :)

Answer (score 1):

hope following link will  help you.

http://developingfor.net/2007/11/29/visual-studio-2008-class-diagram/

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't help. Class Diagram is something else than Modeling Project. Class diagram is simplified class design tool available in all C# projects. Modeling Project is a new feature in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (hence the lack of materials online) and is a full-blown UML architecture designer with Class, Process, Sequence, Layer and other diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above was useful to me. Here's how to enable C# language concepts:

- Make sure you already have a modelling project or create one
- In Visual studio select Architecture -> Windows -> UML model explorer
- Select your modelling project and open the properties panel
- Under "Profiles" hit the "C# profile" checkbox.

To add an event to a class diagram:

- Create a new attribute on a class.
- In the properties panel check "C# event" in stereotypes

Sadly there is no visual indication on the attribute to mark it as an event.

Answer (score -1):

You should try including Observer\Event Pattern. It is discussed very well here. http://www.cumps.be/nl/blog/read/design-patterns-observer-event-pattern

Comment: How does this help me? The event is required there (event *is* the implementation of Observer pattern). I need to find a way to represent event in UML, not avoid using events.

Comment: i don't think we have a direct way of representing events in a UML Diagram.